# Get pristine value in Angular controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, ng-controller

I need to be able to see in the Angular controller if the datepicker is pristine or not. Tried all sorts of things including sending the pristine value in a method but cannot get this value. Below is the view code:

```
<form name="myForm">
                                <!-- Datepicker From -->
                                <div class="small-6 medium-5 large-2 columns" ng-if="vm.subViewActive">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input name="valuationDatePickerFrom" ng-model="name" type="text" class="datepicker" id="valuationDatePickerFrom" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" pikaday="vm.datePickerFrom" on-select="vm.selectStartDate(pikaday)" year-range="{{ vm.yearRange }}" >
                                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                                            <label for="valuationDatePickerFrom" class="postfix">
                                                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> From
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                </form>
```

and then I also tried :

```
var isPristine = $scope.myForm.valuationDatePickerFrom.$pristine;
console.log(isPristine);
```

in my controller but cannot get the pristine value. Read lots of posts here but mainly to do with CSS classes and front-end control or setting the pristine state from the backend not **getting or checking the pristine state**.

Thanks anybody that can help.

Answer (score 2):

You are using:

`var isPristine = $scope.myForm.valuationDatePickerFrom.$pristine;`

but your form's name is not `myForm`.

Change `<input name="name"...` `<input name="valuationDatePickerFrom"...`

Then you can use:

`var isPristine = $scope.userForm.valuationDatePickerFrom.$pristine;`

Also, the controller is getting called before the view is created, so no `myForm` exists at the time the controller runs.  Try adding a `$timeout` like so:

```
$timeout(function() {
  var isPristine = $scope.userForm.valuationDatePickerFrom.$pristine;
  console.log(isPristine);
}, 100);
```

[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/WvhRQoSnH8ca0poJ0zrn?p=preview)

Comment: sorry mistake when I reverted changes. Updated question to show actual changes but still have same error: Cannot read property '$pristine' of undefined

Comment: This may be due to the controller running before the view is created.  See updated answer.

Comment: app.js:11706 TypeError: Cannot read property 'valuationDatePickerFrom' of undefined

Comment: I've added a quick plunkr to demonstrate the solution.  The link is above.

Answer (score 1):

The above solution only works on page load, but you need to know this value when the page is being used. Instead pass the value to the controller when an action happens:

`<form name="myForm">
      <input type="text" name="valuationDatePickerFrom" ng-model="valuationDatePicker" ng-blur="alerty(myForm.$pristine)">
    </form>`

`.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.alerty = function(isPristine){
    alert('isPristine: ' + isPristine);
  };`

https://plnkr.co/edit/f0EWvYmoXCn8UOH3QCfE?p=preview